# How to find the location of mouse pointer in span in letters

Tags: javascript, html

How can I find the location of the mouse pointer between the letters of a span element when clicking on it?

I mean: I'm trying to write a WYSIWYG editor without using design mode (something like google-docs word processor). When the user clicks on the text, I want to get the position of the mouse pointer inside the clicked span, not in pixels but in letters.

How does g-docs word processor do it?

The google code looks pretty weird, full of functions named with single letters..

Comment: The google code looks weird because it has been minified - compressed so that the Javascript code takes up as little space as possible but still works. This means functions and variables frequently get renamed to only be 1 or 2 characters long. It also helps obfuscate (make harder to read and understand) their proprietary code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, this is a tall order. Good luck! You will want to look at [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) if you are going to support IE at all.

For well behaved browsers use `document.getSelection()` and `selection.getRangeAt(0)` Here is a demo so you can see it in action. Click on the Hello World text.
http://jsbin.com/ijuvav.

I didn't find a CDN hosting Rangy so I couldn't post an example, but the code would be the mostly the same:

```
function clickHandler() {
  var selection = rangy.getSelection();
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  alert('You clicked on character: ' + range.startOffset);
  console.log(range);
}
```

Comment: It's easier with inputs, there are 2 properties on the input: selectionStart and selectionEnd.